# What is the correct way to use GHA environment variables in code?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, github-actions

I want to define an environment variable in a Github actions workflow file, and then use that variable in a Nextjs application.

Latest effort is: in GHA workflow, I send an environment variable like this:

```
env:
   ENV_VAR: value
```

and then under pages/index.js I want to do something like:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
   <div>{process.env.ENV_VAR}</div>
  )
}
```

But when I deploy the application and navigate to the page, I just observe the value momentarily and then it disappears. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean use it in the application? Your app isn't actually deployed _to_ GHA, presumably, but perhaps it's deployed _by_ it? Are you expecting this to be baked into the app bundle (in which case read https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) or set in an actual production environment?

Comment: I basically want to read the value of this variable that was set in the GHA workflow anywhere in the code. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, no. How's that value supposed to get _out_ of the workflow to wherever your code is deployed (for a start: where is that)?

Comment: in the workflow step, create a file with the environment variable value. something like echo $ENV_VAR > file. Deploy this file with your code. Then in your code, read the value of this file.

Comment: Note that in Next.js environment variables need to be prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to be exposed/available on the client-side. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the variable I was trying to pass was available at build time, so what I could do was something like this:

.github/workflow/.yaml file

```
name: Deploy Next.js site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true
env:
  DEPLOY_ENV: PROD
jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          echo "BRANCH: $GITHUB_REF_NAME"
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=manager::yarn"
            echo "::set-output name=command::install"
            echo "::set-output name=runner::yarn"
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=manager::npm"
            echo "::set-output name=command::ci"
            echo "::set-output name=runner::npx --no-install"
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine packager manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v2
        with:
          # Automatically inject basePath in your Next.js configuration file and disable
          # server side image optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).
          #
          # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
          static_site_generator: next
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            .next/cache
          # Generate a new cache whenever packages or source files change.
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
          # If source files changed but packages didn't, rebuild from a prior cache.
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build
      - name: Static HTML export with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next export
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: ./out

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

and then in a nextjs page I could do this:

```
import React from 'react';
export const getStaticProps = () => {
  return {
    props: {
      deployEnv: process.env.DEPLOY_ENV
    }
  }
}
export default function Home({ deployEnv }: {deployEnv: string}) {
  return (
    <div>{deployEnv}</div>
  )
}
```